# Magento 1 taking too long to login in admin (sometimes)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, magento-1.9.2

I'm checking out a problem occurring in a `Magento 1.9.2.2` instance for a client. Basically, the website becomes really slow sometimes, but the major problem is in Admin Page.

When the user logs in (or logs out) from Admin, it takes too long (about 3 minutes) and just ends up showing a Request Timeout, then when I try to reload the page, it just enters the admin (because the cookies have been created).

So far I have tried the following

- Inspecting `exception.log` and `system.log` files
- Deactivated ALL community and local modules
- Changed redirections
- Cleaned cache and sessions (files and database)
- Changed PHP memory_size and timeout.

The only clue I have I saw in `system.log`. When logging, the `system.log` receives some XML paths, like these:

`/home/nplplkrh/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/core.xml`
`/home/nplplkrh/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`

When the problem occurs, some part of this code just repeats without stopping, as if the code is loading the same XML files uninterruptedly.

The oddest fact is that this problem just occurs sometimes, really often, but not always. I had a whole week without any problem, but it started over again this week.

I appreciate if you guys could help me to debug this problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice for Magento 1.9 speed Optimization

1. Clean database log
2. Caching configuration
3. Magento server configuration optimization
4. Optimize the MySQL server
5. Advantage performance optimization
6. Minimize the third party extension & Keep your site clean
7. Ensure you are running the latest version
8. Choose Best Web Hosting
9. Use optimized Magento themes
10. Optimize Magento Site on Mobile